# Trouble Getting Started with RailsSpace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, aptana

I am using the RailsSpace book to learn RoR but I haven't been able to get past the first step - creating a project.

The issue I believe is that the book is outdated. It says run the command `rails rails_space` but once it runs the command it does not create the app skeleton along with folder structure like the book says it would.

Furthermore when the book tells me to import the rails_space project into the project I just created, what project am I importing? The steps to import it are invalid from what I can tell - they read as follows:

1. Go to File -> New -> Rails -> Rails Project and click Next.
2. Uncheck the Generate Rails application skeleton and Create a WEBrick server boxes.
3. Edit the default location...etc."

Answer (score 1):

Check that you are running `rails new rails_space` and not `rails rails_space` as you noted. If you have write permissions it will create the app skeleton. Definitely consult [this documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) if you are struggling.

Answer (score 0):

http://ruby.railstutorial.org/?railsspace=1

Welcome, RailsSpace.com visitors!

In its time, RailsSpace was the best introduction to Ruby on Rails web development, but it is now out of date. Fortunately, the natural successor to RailsSpace is now out: the Ruby on Rails Tutorial book is available for free online, and is also available for purchase as a PDF or as a print edition. Ruby on Rails Tutorial was directly inspired by RailsSpace, and takes the same step-by-step tutorial approach. We think you will find Ruby on Rails Tutorial to be an easy-to-use and thorough introduction to Ruby on Rails.

—Aurelius Prochazka & Michael Hartl