# Rails test_uniqueness_of_screen_name_and_email

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My question simply put is how do I perform the following uniqueness test:

---

require 'test_helper'

class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

fixtures :users

def setup

```
@error_messages = ActiveRecord::Errors.default_error_messages
@valid_user = users(:valid_user)
@invalid_user = users(:invalid_user)  end
```

test "test_uniqueness_of_screen_name_and_email" do

```
user_repeat = User.new(:screen_name => @valid_user.screen_name,
                       :email       => @valid_user.email,
                       :password    => @valid_user.password)
assert !user_repeat.valid?
assert_equal @error_messages[:taken], user_repeat.errors.on[:screen_name]
assert_equal @error_messages[:taken], user_repeat.errors.on[:email]  end
```

end

---

This is referencing an example in the book RailsSpace - Section 5.6 Detailed User model testing for those who are familiar. I could list all the partial clues that have kind of all but not helped me solve my problem but I would prefer if someone could simply drop knowledge on how we perform the following test in rails 3 vs the year 2008 when this book was printed.

Note: I've seen a lot of talk about i18n and I believe that it should not be the direction I want to go as I don't care about locales or different languages (yet) and want to focus on learning about testing.

Answer (score 0):

What Ed Jones said about the Ruby on Rails Tutorial book is correct. It wills save you from any issues your experiencing in RailsSpace.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16223598/2320716